# How To Get Cell GridView Devexpress For Edited When Row Selected

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, cell

I have the GridView like

[image]

i choose one row and show up menu edit, when i edit the selected row.
How i get cell coloumn "Ket" focused and enable to edit that like :

[image]

Please help me to prepare that, thank you...

Comment: Ask devexpress support. They are amazing.

Answer (score 0):

To focus a column, use the [GridView.FocusedColumn](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.FocusedColumn.property) property:

```
gridView1.FocusedColumn = gridView1.Columns["Ket"];
```

Then activate an inplace editor by calling the [GridView.ShowEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.ShowEditor.method) method:

```
gridView1.ShowEditor();
```

Comment: thanks @Dmitry ,  I use the way as above, but all the column "ket" to be edited.. but how to handle only one selected column that can be edited?

Answer (score 0):

Handle `GridView.FocusedRowChanged` event and invoke the editor manually via [GridView.ShowEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.ShowEditor.method) method (you have to set focus to desired column first).

```
private void gridView1_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
{
    gridView1.FocusedColumn = gridView1.Columns["Ket"];
    gridView1.ShowEditor();
}
```

Comment: thanks @Marko , but how to handle only one selected column that can be edited?

Comment: So you want **only** Ket to be editable, users can not edit other columns? In that case set their property "OptionsColumn.AllowEdit" to false. You can use ReadOnly property as well (it depends on your scenario).

Comment: i try use property "OptionsColumn.AllowEdit" to false for coloumns other than coloumn "Ket", but all cell in coloumn "Ket" can be edited. I mean how just one cell in coloumn "Ket" can be edited when i selected the row?